# jquery tabs prevent open a new browser window by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Hello I'm really new to jQuery and I'm trying to use tabs with ajax loaded content. 
The links in class menu are working fine, but the links in footer shall also load in the tab-spacer div (what is now not used).

Maybe is tab also not the correct thing for me, i just want ajax loaded content in the tab-spacer div. And I want to have displayed any content from any link in this div. I hope you can help me!

this is my code

```
   <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="js/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="js/jquery/js//jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script><script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Error" );
        });
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

<script>
$('#tabs').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.panel).delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">


      <div class="container">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs">
        <div class="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3.php">3</a></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-spacer" class="tabs-spacer tab-style"></div>
        <div id="tabs-1">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque tortor velit, suscipit at luctus vitae, lobortis facilisis arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque tempor magna a lorem tempor luctus. Curabitur erat nisl, rutrum adipiscing imperdiet ac, elementum et magna. Vivamus id erat sapien. Nam sapien justo, elementum vel blandit commodo, tristique ac ligula. Duis interdum, elit sit amet molestie hendrerit, ligula lacus consequat tortor, sed tempor arcu velit vel nibh. Etiam condimentum erat at mauris malesuada sollicitudin tincidunt mi ultricies. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis mollis, turpis at porttitor pharetra, magna tellus faucibus libero, ut vehicula tortor nunc quis erat. Nunc tristique nibh eu sapien cursus ac imperdiet eros malesuada. </p>


     </div><div class="footer"><ul><li><a href="ajax/4.php" id ="link">4</a></li>
                                                                 <li><a href="ajax/5.php" id ="link">5</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="ajax/6.php" id ="link">6</a></li>

     </ul></div></div>
```

Comment: Use on() instead of delegate. [*As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Unfortunately it also don't work with on.
I've tried this

<script>
$('#tabs').tabs({
    load: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.panel).on('a', 'click', function(event) {
            $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
</script></code>

Answer (score 0):

Mhh I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm working now on a solution without jQueryUI's tab function

I have tried already adding these scripts after including jquery.js in my head section:

```
$('#link').live('click', function(ev) {
    // Stop regular handling of "click" in most non-IE browsers
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();

    // Load the new content into the div (same code you had)
    $('#tabs-spacer').load($(this).attr('href'));

    // Stop regular handling of "click" in IE (and some others)
    return false;
});
```

Off course all links have the id =link

and i've tried this also:

```
<script>
$('#link').bind('click', function(event) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tabs-spacer').load(url);
    return false;  // cancel anchor action
});</script>
```

But nothing works, all links are loaded with leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$('#link').click(function(){return false;});
```